# How call the function on multiDatesPicker date select

Tags: php, jquery, html

I need to call the function on  multiDatesPicker date select event.

```
I have used below  code for display the multidateselect,

  $('#from-input').multiDatesPicker();
```

Here, I need to call the function on date select in multiDatesPicker. How can I do. Please help me.

Comment: What code have you tried ? If you haven't tried anything i suggest you trying something, and show it, since this isn't a code generator sevice.

Comment: I tried $('#from-input').multiDatesPicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
         alert(dateText);
    }
});

Comment: you need to the multiDatesPicker supported js.did u include that  ?

Comment: please add your code in fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Use this [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/URcqn/168/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var datesArr = [];

       datesArr.push(new Date ('Mon Jul 02 00:00:00 EDT 2012'));

    $('#date').multiDatesPicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        addDates: datesArr
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

use onSelect

```
$('.date').multiDatesPicker({ 
   onSelect: function(date){ //do something with the date} 
})
```